# How to get my SQL database out of Google Cloud SDK Repo

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a sqlite database that to date has been stored in my Google App Engine SDK repo. I have recently learned that this is not best practice and now I am trying to move my database from the SDK repo and to Cloud SQL.

*The Question*

How can I copy my `site.db` file in order to migrate it to cloud? The DB does have data and I am worried about losing that data.

*What I have tried*
I thought that I would be able to just `git commit` and `git push` back to the master branch, and then I would be able to do what I want with the migration, but when I try that, it just says that the repo is `Already up to date.` So at this stage my data is stuck in the SDK.

I'm sure that there is something simple I am missing here. Probably a git command, since I am admittedly not that knowledgable with git workflow. Could someone please steer me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy your DB from repo, firstly, you need to clone it with ['gcloud source repos clone'](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/source/repos/clone) command in Google Cloud Shell. Now you have cloned repository on your machine, use 'cd [REPOSITORY NAME]' here you have all files from the repository. You can use ['gsutil cp'](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) to copy file.